# AWS Route53 Associate Health Check to Alias Resource Record Set

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was reading a section of the AWS Route53 documentation titled, "What Happens When You Associate a Health Check with an Alias Resource Record Set?" and this question naturally came up.

Why would you ever want to associate a health check to an alias resource record set?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-complex-configs.html#dns-failover-complex-configs-hc-alias

Answer (score 0):

One example is if you use GSLB, meaning to access your website (assuming it's a website we are talking about) you have two or more DNS entries and you set them up as "Always Serve". If you don't check for the health of your DNS entries then your traffic could potentially be routed to a high latency DNS entry (which you don't want).

More in the context of AWS and Route 53, they want you to use multiple *DNS entries* to access your final destination depending on the region say where your servers are running. That way if one of them has high latency or it's down the appropriate check will allow you to route traffic to the healthy region (using DNS)

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

*DNS Entries*: means a CNAME entry on Route 53 which generally is a load balancer or it could be and A PTR entry which is a server IP address.

Comment: When you say "DNS entries" are you talking about "DNS servers?" The health check is applied to a physical machine. So it only makes sense that the health check is performed on a DNS _server_.

Comment: No, DNS entries means CNAME or A DNS records. Check the [Edit] section.

Comment: What I don't get is why you can associate a health check to a DNS entry. DNS entry is not a physical machine. So there is no "health" to assess. Unless by "associating a health check", they mean that the result of following through a particular DNS entry will result in high latency and therefore does not pass a criterion. But even so, wouldn't "Evaluate Health Check" already take care of the high latency scenario? The DNS entry will be a pointer to a Load Balancer. The load balancer will have a health check that makes sure the EC2 it points to return results in a timely manner.

Comment: Not necessarily, like I said if you are using different regions, your DNS request response (translation to IP Address) might be fine in New York, but it may not respond or it may have a high latency from LA or China or London. Its use really depends on how you architect your app/system too and what kind of traffic your are getting (Global, local, etc?). This also comes into play when you start using the AWS regions.  If you are not using Amazon, low latency DNS providers also allow you to do this (Dynect for example calls it traffic management). In the load balancer world this is called GSLB.